# pydev messes with @= (operator.__imatmul__)

Tags: eclipse, pydev

[PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) (version: 6.3.2) seems to be unaware of the `@=` operator ([`operator.__imatmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__imatmul__)) even when setting the 'Grammar Version' to `3.6`.

whenever i save a file containing an `@=` operator (using 'Save Actions' such as 'Auto-format') this operator will get a space in between and result in `@ =` which is a syntax error in python.

is there a way to fix that (or at least ignore that special operator)?

Comment: In eclipse, in settings->code formatter, you can define your own rule. There you should be able to define to not put a space betwween @ and =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a bug in the PyDev code formatter.

Please report this as a bug in the pydev tracker (https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/) -- I'll make this a priority for the next release (although 6.3.2 was just released, so, a release with the fix will probably be a month away).

Comment: ok, done that: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/904 (hope i did it correctly...). thanks a lot and thanks for PyDev!